# Is necessary to use conio.h in c?

Tags: c

I'm a beginner in coding and I was practicing coding. I wanted to know that is it necessary to use **conio.h** in *C Programming*. Because I was able to run my program without using **conio.h**.

Comment: Why have you tagged 3 other languages and html?

Comment: The `conio.h` header file is a left-over from the old DOS days. It's all but obsolete.

Comment: `<conio.h>` is not specified by the C Standard. It provides functionality that is only available in specific implementations (DOS). You are better off not using any of the functionality ... or, if you must, use a different library with larger scope (not only DOS), like eg [`ncurses`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses)

Comment: `conio.h` is used by MS VC for non-GUI console operations, rather than `stdin` and `stdout` streams (which can be redirected). If you don't need it, don't `#include` it.

Comment: Nobody uses conio.h since the MS DOS days. You are leaning C from a completely outdated source.

Comment: Without seeing your source code it is impossible to tell if you use a function from `conio.h` or not. "*I was able to run my program without using `conio.h`*" can mean that either you don't use a function declared in `conio.h` and thererfore don't need to (should not) include it or that you do use a function from `conio.h` and your program gets compiled anyway without the `#include` because the function is declares implicitly. In the latter case it is an error to omit the `#include`.

Answer (score 2):

> Is necessary to use conio.h in c?

If you don't use any declaration from a header, then you don't need to include it. There's nothing in the conio.h header that must be used to write a C program in general.

In fact, conio.h is a non-standard platform specific header on an ancient and obsolete operating system and shouldn't be used at all if your goal is to write modern cross platform programs - which is a reasonable goal to have.

Comment: Love the description of Windows OS!

Comment: @WeatherVane It's description of MS-DOS :) Windows may still provide the header, but does anyone use it to write new programs?

Comment: Only for my own use, but not with MS-DOS (which is dead). I find it useful to output cues that I specifically don't want in the `stdout` stream. It's also useful as an easy way to input unbuffered keystrokes from the keyboard (not `stdin`). I have never liked the line-oriented way that `getchar()` works. It's a convenient thing to have around, and I am not going to start criticising non-standard Linux libraries.